# Is it possible to manipulate css variables using LESS?

Tags: less, css-variables

With preprocessor variables it's easy to set up one variable and manipulate it so that I can use it to set multiple properties. ([demo](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/aNzGdM))

While experimenting with [native css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables), I noticed that I could combine them with preprocessor variables, so in [the following example](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/WwbJKy?editors=1100): (use firefox)

```
h1 {
  --length: 40px;
  @length: var(--length);
  line-height: @length;
  border: 5px solid tomato;
}
```

line-height was correctly rendered at 40px

**But**, when I tried to manipulate the preprocessor variable - [like this](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/QNwxLJ?editors=1100):

```
h1 {
  --length: 40px;
  @length: var(--length);
  @length2: @length*2;
  line-height: @length;
  padding: @length2;
  border: 5px solid tomato;
}
```

... the code failed.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: If I am not wrong `var(--length)` is resolved to its value by UA which is after the Less compiler compiles the code into CSS. At the time of compilation, the value of `@length` is only `var(--length)` which is not a number and hence results in compilation error. Try doing it as `@length2: @length ~"* 2";` and see if it works. I can't test because my browser is old. Or even `@length2: ~"calc(@{length} * 2)";`.

Comment: @Harry - the result is that padding gets the value: `var(--length) * 2;`

Comment: WIth the `calc()` wrapped around? Both these are just guesses though. Are you able to apply math operations to CSS variables without using pre-processor?

Comment: @Harry - Yes that works! Please add that as an answer for me to accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, my understanding of CSS variables is that the variable is resolved into its actual value by the UA.  This happens after the Less compiler compiles the file and thus it wouldn't be aware of what is the actual value contained by the CSS variable.

To the compiler, the value of `@length` is only `var(--length)`. Since this is not a number, an error is thrown during compilation indicating that the math operation is being done on an invalid type.

> OperationError: Operation on an invalid type on line 4, column 3:

One way to fix this would be to make the Less compiler output the variable name as it is and have the multiplier appended to it (like string concatenation). This would then leave the control to the UA.

But since all CSS math operations have to be given within `calc()` function, the entire thing has to be wrapped within it. So, the below code would work fine.

```css
h1 {
  --length: 40px;
  @length: var(--length);
  @length2: ~"calc(@{length} * 2)";
  line-height: @length;
  padding: @length2;
  border: 5px solid tomato;
}
```

Or, even the below would be enough if `--strict-math` is enabled during compilation:

```css
h1 {
  --length: 40px;
  @length: var(--length);
  @length2: calc(@length * 2);
  line-height: @length;
  padding: @length2;
  border: 5px solid tomato;
}
```

---

Above code when compiled produces an output similar to the one in [Example 11 of the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/) and so it should be a reasonably good way of doing this :)

> ... Note, though, that `calc()` can be used to validly achieve the same thing, like so:
>
> ```
> .foo {
>   --gap: 20;
>   margin-top: calc(var(--gap) * 1px);
> }
> ```
>
> var() functions are substituted at computed-value time...